# RestSharp + Server Down - How do you know if server is down?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am wondering how can I check if the RestSharp request I made failed because the server is down vs something else.

When I shutdown my server I get a status code of "NotFound" but that could be a particular record was not found(which I do on my site if say they try to find a record that might be recently deleted).

How can I figure out the server is actually down?

Edit

here is my code

```
   private readonly RestClient client = new RestClient(GlobalVariables.ApiUrl);
          var request = new RestRequest("MyController", Method.POST);
                request.AddParameter("UserId", "1");
                request.AddParameter("Name", name.Trim());

                var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
                {
                    var status = response.StatusCode;
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

When the server is down, it should not return a "404 NotFound" error.

The most appropriate in this case is [HTTP Error 503 - Service unavailable](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html)

> The Web server (running the Web site) is currently unable to handle
>   the HTTP request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the
>   server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which
>   will be alleviated after some delay. Some servers in this state may
>   also simply refuse the socket connection, in which case a different
>   error may be generated because the socket creation timed out.

That way checking that `RestResponse.StatusCode` is `503` it will tell you that the server is down.

Comment: Myabe it is different on a production server but locally it comes back as NotFound when I run my code in the WP8 Emulator

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue.

I decided to check for the ContentLength too. At least my webservice always returns ContentLength>0 (even for NotFound occurrences). This seems to work out.

```
if ( response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound &&
                response.ContentLength == -1 ){
   ==> client couldn't connect to webservice
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I needed to check if anything happened to the connection, e.g. connection time out, can't resolve the host name, etc. So I also added following code:

```
try
{
    var client = new RestClient(_configuration.ServerUrl);
    var request = new RestRequest
    {
        Resource = _configuration.SomeUrl,
        Method = Method.POST
    };

    var response = client.Execute(request);
    if (response.ErrorException != null)
    {
        throw response.ErrorException;
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    // TODO: check ex.Status, if it matches one of needed conditions.
}
```

For more information about WebExceptionStatus Enumeration, please, see following link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus(v=vs.110).aspx